# how to get postmeta info based on multiple categories?

Tags: categories, query, post-meta, mysql

I need to get one `meta_value` from wp_postmeta and I can do it with one category but I'm having problem when using another one.

I have:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_application'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = '14'
```

and my results are:

```
ID | meta_value
91 | email@email.com
99 | email3@email.com
```

when I change last line `wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = '14'` to `wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = '31'` i will get:

```
ID | meta_value
91 | email@email.com
95 | email2@email.com
```

Problem starts when I use 2 categories

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_application'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = '14'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = '31'
```

then I will get nothing

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

and I should get:

```
ID | meta_value
91 | email@email.com
```

How can I use both categories (`term_id = '14'` and `term_id = '31'` ) at the same time in one query so my results will show only meta_values for posts that are in both categories?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I was close and I have solution:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta    
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_application'
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (31) 
  AND 
  tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (14)
)
```